# Get cumulative sum and mean for specifc columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, sum, aggregate

I have a dataframe:

```
# create example df
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
df['ID'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
df['election_date'] = pd.date_range("01/01/2010", periods=6, freq="M")
df['stock_price'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

# sort values
df.sort_values(['election_date'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df

    ID  election_date   stock_price
6   2   2010-06-30       6
5   2   2010-05-31       5
4   2   2010-04-30       4
3   1   2010-03-31       3
2   1   2010-02-28       2
1   1   2010-01-31       1
```

My goal is to calculate the cumulative sum AND mean for the column `stock_price` for every `ID`. I was successful with calculating the cumulative sum:

```
df['stock_price_sum_past'] = (df.iloc[::-1]
               .groupby('ID')['stock_price']
               .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
               .fillna(0)
               .astype(int))


    ID  election_date   stock_price stock_price_sum_past
6   2    2010-06-30          6             9
5   2    2010-05-31          5             4
4   2    2010-04-30          4             0
3   1    2010-03-31          3             3
2   1    2010-02-28          2             1
1   1    2010-01-31          1             0
```

I was not successful with calculating the cumulative mean for the column `stock_price`. Additionally I do not understand how to get the cummulative count for the column `election_date`. I know there is sth like [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), but I don't understand how to apply it for my problem.

EDIT:

I believe this is the expected cum mean:

```
ID  election_date   stock_price stock_price_sum_past    stock_price_mean_past
6   2   2010-06-30       6            9                        4.5
5   2   2010-05-31       5            4                        4.0
4   2   2010-04-30       4            0                        NaN
3   1   2010-03-31       3            3                        1.5
2   1   2010-02-28       2            1                        1.0
1   1   2010-01-31       1            0                        NaN
```

I guess you could replace NaN with 0. Depends on your definition of `mean`

Comment: What is the reason of inverting the dataframe `df.iloc[::-1]`?

Comment: This is needed to shift the result. Without it, it doens't work. Please try the example. Hard to explain in words :-)

Comment: Instead of inverting i guess we could also sort the date column in ascending order?

Comment: Well, I think this should work!

Comment: What is the expected output for `cummulative` mean?

Comment: I have added it to my first post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `sort` the dataframe on `election_date` and create a sequeantial counter using `groupby` and `cumcount`, then divide this `counter` by the cumulative sum per `ID` to get the cumulative mean

```
df = df.sort_values('election_date')
grp =  df.groupby('ID')['stock_price']
df['cum_sum'] = grp.apply(lambda p: p.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
df['cum_mean'] = df['cum_sum'] / grp.cumcount()
```

---

```
   ID election_date  stock_price  cum_sum  cum_mean
1   1    2010-01-31            1        0       NaN
2   1    2010-02-28            2        1       1.0
3   1    2010-03-31            3        3       1.5
4   2    2010-04-30            4        0       NaN
5   2    2010-05-31            5        4       4.0
6   2    2010-06-30            6        9       4.5
```

P.S: The resulting dataframe is sorted on `date` in ascending order.

Comment: Looks very promising! Do you know how to answer the second part of my question? I need to know the ``cumcount`` for the column ``election_date``

Comment: You can assign the result of `grp.cumcount()` to the column for example we can do `df['cum_count'] = grp.cumcount()`

Comment: @PParker Pleased to help.